# Excel VBA select column refence cell formula

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to do the following:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A2").Select
```

Where in `A2` I have the following formula:

```
=WEEKNUM(NOW())
```

The formula can be merged probably.

The reference to cell `A2` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Value).Select
```

worked for me,...  I think you just needed one more level of indirection to dig the value out of `A2`.